# How to force Vista explorer to display reasonable columns?

Tags: windows-vista, file-management, windows-explorer

I have four .zip files in a directory.

Vista Explorer displays them and gives me the columns:

- Date taken (???)
- Tags
- Size
- Rating

I want, however:

- Date last modified
- Size

I know I can right-click the headers and change this but I have to do this every time and it gets tedious. **How can I tell Windows vista explorer "always for every kind of file in any directory, just show me Date-last-modified and Size and also automatically show the full file name so I don't always have to expand it to see the full names of my files"**

[image]

Comment: This is the top answer to the Windows Annoyances question. http://superuser.com/questions/5564/windows-annoyances

Comment: Vista looks at the files and thinks, "Good compression, will zip again. A++++!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is "Folder Templates". It appears that folder is using a "Pictures and Videos" template, but this can easily be changed.

- Right click the folder you wish to change
- Choose Properties -> "Customize" tab
- Choose a template from the drop down list, you will probably want "All Items" template.
- Apply & OK.

Comment: While this works for the folder in question, it certainly does not prevent my Vista from defaulting to "Pictures and Videos" in virtually any folder that I create. Gets a bit annoying to do this in the long run...

Answer (score 1):

A problem I often encountered is that even after resetting a folder to "All Items", it tends to revert back to a different template occasionaly. It annoyed the hell out of me.
A solution can be found [here](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/11/08/delete-and-reset-windows-vista-folder-views-or-folder-types-settings-to-default-clean-state/) - regedit, so be careful to back it up.

Answer (score 1):

Another tip.

To get each column to size to fit the contents, press Control-+ on the num pad (you have to use the plus sign on the num pad).

In Windows 7 if you right click on the column header there are two options to resize all columns to fit or just a single column.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to your "documents" folder. Right click - property - customise - tick "apply to all subfolders"